# How to get rid of blue background on div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have these Groups of people (**Group** A, **Group B** and **Group C**) and next to each group text there's a **toggle to hide/show** the people for each group (**"+"** and **"-"** buttons).

My issue is that when I click on the "+" o "-" buttons to hide/show a section I end up having a **blue focus color**. Does anyone know how to get rid of the blue color? In order to see the blue color you must click on the toggle fast enough. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a picture of my issue:

[image]

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        {post.label}{" "}
        <span onClick={() => setShowGroup(!showGroup)}>
          {showGroup ? "-" : "+"}
        </span>
      </h2>
      {showGroup && (
        <div>
          {post.fields?.map((field: any, idx: number) => {
            const key = `${post.label}__${field.name}`;
            const isChecked = checkboxStates[key] || false;
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={isChecked}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleCheckboxChange(field, e.target.checked)
                  }
                />
                <span>{field?.name}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You should be using labels!!! Use HTML like it is intended....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `+/-` "button" (currently a `span`) into a real `button` element, and it'll properly handle the button focus.

You can easily use CSS styling to remove any unwanted button stylings

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting text. When you click fast three times, a paragraph is selected.

You can use `user-select` CSS to disable select action at all.

```js
...
 return (
    <div style={{userSelect: 'none'}}>
      <h2>
...
```

Comment: This isn't a real solution. This is like telling someone to wear gloves because they keep slicing up their hands when they break their window trying to get into their car - rather than using their key.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi You might be right. But it's also good to tell someone why their hands hurt first. And they may just want to stick to their approach.